# What is an intuitive of definition of "point identification" (point identified parameter) in econometrics?

Tags: estimators, point-estimation, identifiability

I've recently come across the notion of **point identification** in several econometric papers.

See, e.g., https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/tamer/files/pie.pdf, who mentions **point identification** numerous times but doesn't give a clear definition.

I'm not entirely sure what it means, but, intuitively, from the given context I would assume that the statement "parameter $\theta$ is **point identified**" is equivalent to saying "parameter $\theta$ is *uniquely identified*".

Is this correct? I'm grateful for any attempts to clarify this concept!